# SPSS Ranking Syntax

Tags: statistics, spss

I have ten variables with an int value of 1-10. The 1-10 number is the rank for the corresponding variable. Now I want to get the mean rank of each variable.
In Excel it would be something like this (in a simplified ranking with only three variables): v_1=((1*A1+2*A2+3*A3)/SUM(A1:A3))
The values of the ten variables are like this: 1=1, 2=2, 3=3 etc.
How could I compute this in SPSS?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of the EXCEL formula you state in SPSS would be:

```
COMPUTE v_1=(1*A1 + 2*A2 + 3*A3) / SUM(A1,A2,A3).
```

However, it seems you want a variable-wise mean score, for which, take a look at either [MEANS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_means_overview.htm) or [AGGREGATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_aggregate_overview.htm).

Comment: Yeah, but how can I use the different values of the variable instead of A1, A2...? It must be something like 1*v_123(1)+2*v_123(2)...

Comment: I don't understand, sorry? Initial question is somewhat ambiguous despite stating the Excel formula as a way of helping demonstrate the problem you face, I think that is not what you are after. You may want to further clarify. If A1, A2 & A3 store ranks, I suspect all three variables can contain any value from 1 to 3 (and for each case it would contain the entire unique set 1,2,3 across all A1,A2,A3). So perhaps you are after a variable-wise mean rather than case-wise?

Comment: Okay, I try to rephrase it: I have done a survey with questback and there is a ranking question where x variables have to be sorted by priority (rank). The SPSS export for each variable of this looks like v_1 int
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
Now I want to compute the average rank/priority for each of the x (10 in my case) variables. This could be done in Excel with a formula like above but I don't know how to do it in SPSS directly.

Comment: OK, lets stick with an example of three variables to be ranked. Say, for example, a respondent is asked to rank in order of favourite car manufacture AUDI, BMW & VW. These 3 variables are stored as V1 (AUDI), V2 (BMW) and V3 (VW) and each respondents respective rank score is stored within these 3 columns/variables of data? You then want to create an average rank score for AUDI? Another of BMW? ect? Or am I barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.